# php date function is returning wrong year

Tags: php, date

I can't figure this out for the life of me. I have a date that needs to be formatted. There are multiple dates on the page that format just fine.

```
echo date('M jS o',strtotime('2012-12-31')) //is returning "Dec 31st 2013". 
echo date('M jS o',strtotime('2013-12-31')) //is returning "Dec 31st 2014".
```

and so on, going forward the year is always one year off.

but

```
date('M jS o',strtotime('2011-12-31')) //returns correctly "Dec 31st 2011". 
date('M jS o',strtotime('2010-12-31')) //returns correctly "Dec 31st 2010".
```

and so on, going backward they are fine. Is this some apocalyptic scheme the Mayans threw at us or something? :)

Any ideas? I assume there is a simple answer.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 8):

Use `Y` for year, not `o`. Per the `date` docs:

> `o`: ISO-8601 year number. This has the same value as Y, except that **if the ISO week number (W) belongs to the previous or next year, that year is used instead**. (added in PHP 5.1.0)

Comment: I just saw that. I was using o trying to adhere to the ISO-8601 rule. Guess that backfired. I will change this, thanks! Is there a reason why the previous year to 2012 are not registering the 31st as the following year?

Comment: Depends which weekday the 31st falls on.